# Prototype of "localstorage" in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I currently have added some methods to "localStorage".

```
/**
 *
 * MOVED TO: https://github.com/iFind/html5MultidimensionalStorage
 *
 * This methods extends the default HTML5 Storage object and add support
 * to set and get multidimensional data
 *
 * @example Storage.setObj('users.albums.sexPistols',"blah");
 * @example Storage.setObj('users.albums.sexPistols',{ sid : "My Way", nancy : "Bitch" });
 * @example Storage.setObj('users.albums.sexPistols.sid',"Other songs");
 *
 * @example Storage.getObj('users');
 * @example Storage.getObj('users.albums');
 * @example Storage.getObj('users.albums.sexPistols');
 * @example Storage.getObj('users.albums.sexPistols.sid');
 * @example Storage.getObj('users.albums.sexPistols.nancy');
 *
 * This is just a prototype and is not recommended to use at production apps
 * USE AT YOUR OWN RISK
 *
 * @author Klederson Bueno <klederson@klederson.com>
 * @author Gabor Zsoter <helo@zsitro.com>
 */
//Add Storage support for objects
Storage.prototype.__walker = function(path,o) {
    //Validate if path is an object otherwise returns false
    if(typeof path !== "object")
    return undefined;

    if(path.length === 0){
    return o;
    }

    for(var i in path){
    var prop = path[i];
    //Check if path step exists
    if(o.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        var val = o[prop];
        if(typeof val == 'object'){
        path.splice(0,1);
        return this.__walker(path,val);
        } else {
        return val;
        }
    }
    }
};

Storage.prototype.setObj = function(key, value) {

    var key = encodeURIComponent(key);

    var path = key.split('.');

    //First level is always the localStorage key pair item
    var _key = path[0];
    var os = this.getItem(_key) !== null ? JSON.parse(this.getItem(_key)) : null; //general storage key pair element
    path.splice(0,1);

    if(os === null) {
    os = {};
    this.setItem(_key,JSON.stringify(os));
    }

    var innerWalker = function(path,o) {

    //Validate if path is an object otherwise returns false
    if(typeof path !== "object")
        return undefined;

    if(path.length == 1) {
        o[path[0]] = value;
        return o;
    } else if(path.length === 0) {
        os = value;
        return os;
    }

    var val = null;

    for(var i in path){
        var prop = path[i];
        //Check if path step exists
        if(o.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        val = o[prop];
        if(typeof val == 'object'){
            path.splice(0,1);
            return innerWalker(path,val);
        }
        } else {
        //create depth
        o[prop] = {};
        val = o[prop];
        path.splice(0,1);
        return innerWalker(path,val);
        }
    }
    };

    innerWalker(path,os);

    this.setItem(_key,JSON.stringify(os));
};

Storage.prototype.getObj = function(key) {

    var key = encodeURIComponent(key);
    key = key.split('.');

    //First level is always the localStorage key pair item
    var _key = key[0];
    var o = this.getItem(_key) ? JSON.parse(this.getItem(_key)) : null;

    if(o === null)
    return undefined;

    key.splice(0,1);

    return this.__walker(key,o);
};
```

In another class, I do:

```
define(['jquery', '_Errors'], function($, Errors) {
[...]

    localStorage.getObj('blabla');

[...]
});
```

Before I was migrating to RequireJS i simply had all my functions / prototypes in a file called functions.js - is this still possible? Or do I need to specify all the functions I am going to use in every file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two general choices to load your `functions.js` file:

1. Load the file that modifies `Storage` **outside** of RequireJS. This means putting it in its own `script` element. I would load it **before** RequireJS loads so that everything loaded by RequireJS benefits from changes made by this file.
2. Have RequireJS load `functions.js`. You'd need a configuration like:

   ```
   paths: {
       functions: "path/to/functions.js"
   },
   shim: {
       functions: {
           // This should be something that only your file creates.
           // In some circumstances it is used by RequireJS to check whether something
           // has loaded.
           exports: 'Storage.prototype.getObj'
       }
   }
   ```

   But then **every module** you have that needs to use the functions added by `functions` need to list it among its dependencies:

   ```
   define(['jquery', '_Errors', 'functions'], function ($, Errors) {
       [...]

       localStorage.getObj('blabla');

       [...]
   });
   ```

Whenever I load things that make modifications start modifying things like `Element`, `Node`, or `Storage`, **I prefer to use the first option above**. I want all of this to be loaded first, so that everything that comes after sees the same environment. So it is all loaded outside RequireJS. If you find that performance becomes an issue because you are loading a lot of these small files, you could always customize your optimization step to concatenate these files and add them at the start of the bundle produced by `r.js`.

Comment: Thank you - I ended up using option one, since I already have a filed called "global.js" with a lot of general stuff.